# TypeScript type for recursive simple object?

Tags: typescript

I'm trying to build a type to describe a "simple object", which is an object which contains only primitive types, other objects and arrays which also only contain primitive types... or other objects and arrays, etc etc

```
type Primitive = string | number | boolean
type SimpleArray = Array<Primitive | SimpleObject | SimpleArray>
type SimpleObject = Record<string, Primitive | SimpleObject | SimpleArray>
```

However I am being told that I cannot use the `SimpleObject`type declaration recursively. Is there a way to describe this type?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can fix this by replacing `Record<string, ...>` with `{ [key: string]: ... }` (which is basically the same):

```
type SimpleObject = { [k: string]:  Primitive | SimpleObject | SimpleArray }
```

By the way, you can simplify all the above to:

```
type SimpleObject = string | number | boolean | SimpleObject[] | { [key: string]: SimpleObject };
```